# how to properly move one or more packages into another package in java using code

Tags: java, package, move, eclipse-jdt

I am developing an application [desktop swing application] which requires me to do refactoring via code. [I know the interface and feature is already provided by the eclipse IDE **but I am required to do this via code**

the first phase of refactoring that i require to do is move selected package [the option to select is given via checkboxes that displays all the available packages in the workspace using the idea of JDT. I used tutorial at this location: http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseJDT/article.html ]

Now that I have selected the packages that I wish to move to another package,

I used this piece of code

```
233.   for (IPackageFragment mypackage : packages) {
234.                    if ((mypackage.getKind() == IPackageFragmentRoot.K_SOURCE) && (searchifSelected(mypackage.getElementName())==true) ){
235.                        IJavaElement container = newModule.getPrimaryElement();
236.                        mypackage.move(container, null, null, true, null);
                }
     }
```

**searchifSelected(mypackage.getElementName())==true** tells me if I have selected this particular package to be moved

**IJavaElement container = newModule.getPrimaryElement();** is the container [new package] that will contain the selected packages

**mypackage.move(container, null, null, true, null);** as far as I read it, this command is supposed to move "mypackage" to "container" as a "child".

however, I am facing this problem:

```
 Java Model Exception: Java Model Status [Invalid destination: 'devFromSupplier [in src [in test]]']
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.MultiOperation.processElements(MultiOperation.java:175)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CopyResourceElementsOperation.processElements(CopyResourceElementsOperation.java:417)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.MultiOperation.executeOperation(MultiOperation.java:90)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:728)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:1800)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.runOperation(JavaModelOperation.java:793)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModel.runOperation(JavaModel.java:297)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModel.move(JavaModel.java:258)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.PackageFragment.move(PackageFragment.java:420)
at newmodulewizrd.ui.Integrate.printPackageInfos(Integrate.java:236)
at newmodulewizrd.ui.Integrate.printProjectInfo(Integrate.java:177)
at newmodulewizrd.ui.Integrate.getWorkSpace(Integrate.java:149)
at newmodulewizrd.ui.Integrate.moveToOneModule(Integrate.java:120)
at newmodulewizrd.ui.Integrate$1.actionPerformed(Integrate.java:79)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

which I think means that I am giving the wrong arguments.

**can somebody help what should I do about it?**

Comment: can you include the line numbers to your code segment..

Comment: i am sorry, i did not get ur point?

Comment: @ rana, i have added line numbers

Comment: @carl: i mentioned it earlier, i have to do this via code, without using the feature by IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who r facing the same problem, i found another way to do it, i.e use rename method and make it work as move function. although, it might/might not be the best option.

i replace above code with this code

```
     for (IPackageFragment mypackage : packages) {
                if ((mypackage.getKind() == IPackageFragmentRoot.K_SOURCE) && (searchifSelected(mypackage.getElementName())==true) ){
                    mypackage.rename(textfield.getText()+"."+mypackage.getElementName(), true, null);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I posted the problem on eclipse forum [the IDE that I m using] and then found that the problem/bug with the method that it will not work in the loop. You will have to explicitly call this function one by one. A similar bug has been reported in this link too :

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=240286 [w.r.t delete method]